# import excel received from webservices into sqllite database without download

Tags: html, excel, web-services, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I want to receive an excel file from server using webservices and instead of downloading the file I wish to import the content of file in sqlite database for running on crossplatform mobile application packaged with phonegap for android.
How is it possible ?